# C#/.NET Constructor of WPF-Window is called twice when opened from Mainwindow

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

i have an application which starts with a Mainmenu integrated into the default MainWindow. That works perfectly fine, but now i have to create an automatic dataupdate function which should update the data before the application shows the MainWindow.

This works also fine, but i noticed that at the loading/initializing of the MainWindow my update-window is called twice and therefore the update-function is also called twiced. The Application also runs the constructors of the called Autoupdater-Window twice.

**The code of the MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public MainMenuView()
{
    // Instance needed classes
    DatabaseLock _databaseLock = new DatabaseLock();
    Utils _util = new Utils();
    Eventlog _eventlog  = new Eventlog();

    // Check if auto update had already run today
    if (Settings.Default.LastJSONUpdate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        // Write error to the eventlog
        _eventlog.WriteEventLog("MainMenuView()->MainMenuView.xaml.cs", "foo", _util.GetCurrentUser(), DateTime.Now, Eventlog.Types.INFO);
        // Show info message to the user
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Dataupdate already runned today!", "foo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        // Create lock for table
        _databaseLock.CreateLock("autoupdate", _util.GetCurrentUser());

        // Check if the autoupdate-window is already open and if not open the updater
        if (!_util.CheckIfWinowIsOpened("AutoUpdate"))
        {
            // Minimize the mainmenu window
            _util.MinimizeMaximizeMainMenu();

            // Create new instance of AutoUpdaterView
            View.AutoUpdaterView autoUpdaterView = new View.AutoUpdaterView();
            // Show the window
            autoUpdaterView.Show();

            // Disable the mainwindow
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows[0].IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I tried to move the code to the cs-File of the UserControl itself, but that didn't helped, the result was the same.

So i hope somebody can bring some light to my thoughts.

Thanks in advance
GeoCoder

Comment: Often when a constructor is called it triggers event which may need to be ignored until the constructor is completed.  A Show method should not be put into a constructor.  You may want a Load event and put the Show in the event.   Any code before the InitializeComponent() should only set parameters.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your reply. Am i understanding that right - things that should be done after the Window is loaded should be handled in the Load-Completed-Event?

Comment: Following is from 2007 and still applies : http://fuchangmiao.blogspot.com/2007/11/aspnet-20-page-lifecycle.html

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the link, that explains a lot! I'll try it and provide some feedback.

Comment: I'd suggest a different approach.  If the data isn't related directly to the view, it would be better to load it at the start of the application, rather than the view, which can be done in App.xaml.cs in WPF by overriding OnStartup.  Try to keep view logic and business logic separate whenever possible.

Comment: I've tried all solutions suggested here. The solution that worked for me was to create a own UserControl für the Update-Screen and show it via popup at the MainWindow. Now all Messages are loaded only once.  Thanks for all your suggestions and comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried all solutions suggested in the Comments.

The solution that worked for me was to create a own UserControl für the Update-Screen and show it via popup at the MainWindow. Now all Messages are loaded only once.

Thanks for all your suggestions and comments!